# Deep Linking Foundation 5 Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, zurb-foundation, deep-linking

***Update***

As of [v5.5.1](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/changelog.html#5-5-1-january-29th-2015) Foundation Tabs support deep linking.

---

Deep linking doesn't work with Foundation 5 Tabs so I am attempting to work on a hack.

My thought is to use jQuery to trigger a click on the appropriate tab but it isn't working.

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
$(function() {
  $(window).on('load', function () {
    $(hash).trigger( "click" );
    console.log(hash)
  });
});
```

The `console.log` shows the correct hash but the "click" doesn't appear to work.

I would like to know any workarounds or hacks that allow me deep link Foundation 5 Tabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now supported as standard by Foundation 5 via the attribute `data-options="deep_linking:true"`

From the [docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tabs.html):

> The tabs Foundation component can parse the location hash value and open the corresponding tab content pane. To enable deep linking set data-options="deep_linking:true". If the location hash maps to an element ID within a tab content pane, then the appropriate tab will become active and the browser window will scroll to the specified element. If you do not want to scroll to the specified element then set data-options="scroll_to_content: false".

Answer (score 4):

You can also set this via JS in the Foundation init:

```
$(document).foundation({
    tab: {
        deep_linking:true       
    }
});
```

And if you don't want the page to scroll to the newly selected tab, you can do this:

```
$(document).foundation({
    tab: {
        deep_linking:true,
        scroll_to_content: false
    }
});
```

Comment: Problem is that you can't disable `scroll_to_content` while having `deep_linking`, no matter if you set is with JS or with data attributes `data-options="deep_linking:true;scroll_to_content: false"`. Github issue https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/4791 and Trello list of known issues where you can vote for it https://trello.com/c/FXTkqxPn/110-tabs-deep-linking-no-scroll-not-working

Answer (score 3):

This was the solution to how to Deep Link Tabs in Foundation 5.

```
if(window.location.hash){
    $('dl.tabs dd a').each(function(){
        var hash = '#' + $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
        if(hash == window.location.hash){
            $(this).click();
        }
    });         
}
```

[Reference can be found here.](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/3692)