# Foundation 6 deep linking nested tabs

Tags: zurb-foundation, deep-linking

Hej all !

As the title of the subject suggest, I wonder if it's possible to have deep linking  that works on nested tabs.
I mean, if I use only one tabs container, it works fine, but I don't know how to deep link to a tab inside a parent tab. It should first open the parent tab and then display the goal child tab.
Is it possible using Foundation 6 deep-linking please (without hacks) ?

Let's say we have this code :

```
<div>
    <ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="tabs" data-deep-link="true">
        <li class="tabs-title is-active"><a href="#tab1">Content 1</a></li>
        <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#tab2">Content 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="tabs">
    <div class="tabs-panel is-active" id="tab1">
        My Content 1
    </div>
    <div class="tabs-panel" id="tab2">
        <ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="tab2-tabs" data-deep-link="true">
            <li class="tabs-title is-active"><a href="#tab2-tab1">Content 2-1</a></li>
            <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#tab2-tab2">Content 2-2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="tab2-tabs">
            <div class="tabs-panel is-active" id="tab2-tab1">
                My Content 2-1
            </div>
            <div class="tabs-panel" id="tab2-tab2">
                My Content 2-2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I open "My Content 2-2" using deep-linking please ?

Comment: using example.com/thispage#tab2-tab2

Comment: Hej @L.Antonelli, Tnhanks for your reply. I agree but first, it should open tab2. If not, it will not display the sub part.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894632/deep-linking-foundation-5-tabs?rq=1

Comment: No it's a simple page. But by default, tab1 is displayed, so if I want to display tab2-tab2, it must open tab2 first (the parent)